# Number of solutions to the congruence $x^q \equiv 1 \mod p$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $p, q$ be distinct odd primes, I would like to compute the number of solution $\mod p$ to the congruence $x^q \equiv 1 \mod p$. (Show that it's $gcd(q, p - 1))$

If $x^q \equiv 1 \mod p$, since $q$ is prime, this must mean that $x$ is either $1$ or has order $q$.   Hence, the problem reduces to finding the number of elements of $U_p$ which is either $1$ or has order $q$.  If $ q \nmid  p - 1$, then there is only one element, namely $1$.  If $q \mid p - 1$, then the number of elements of order $q$ is $\phi(q) = q - 1$, and so the number of solutions to the congruence $\mod p$ is $q - 1 + 1 = q$, and in either case the number of solutions is $\gcd(q, p - 1)$.

Does this look fine?

Comment: Yes, it sounds fine, given you have already done the theorems implicitly quoted. A fairly simple argument using a primitive root of $p$ (generator of the multiplicative group) proves the same result for $x^k\equiv 1\pmod{p}$, where $k$ is not necessarily prime.

Answer (score 6):

The key to questions like this is that (1) the group of nonzero elements of $\mathbb Z/(p)$ is cyclic of order $p-1$; and (2) in a cyclic group of order $n$, there is just one subgroup of order $d$ for every divisor $d$ of $n$, and these are the only subgroups of the original cyclic group. Now you fill in the details.